# Add-Ins disabled/not showing in Word Online with WOPI integration

Tags: office365, office-addins, word-addins, ms-wopi

it would be very nice if someone could help me with my problem:

I am implementing a WOPI integration for editing a Word document in Word Online (Office 365).
The integration works wonderfully. The WOPI validator tests are error-free.

What doesn't work: The Add-Ins button on the Word Online Insert toolbar is not visible. The user cannot activate any Add-Ins.

[Insert toolbar in Word Online with missing Add-Ins button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H1Kb.png)

Here are some key data about my integration:

- Use the Office 365 test system: https://ffc-onenote.officeapps.live.com
- Business User Flow activated in Action URL (BUSINESS_USER = 1)
- CheckFileInfo delivers:

```
    {
      "BaseFileName": "Test.docx",
      "OwnerId": "46659068-53d1-4d97-b1a4-6c0dc1336cff",
      "Size": 12345,
      "UserId": "ac3aa4ef-836d-4a42-ae3d-307f4b0e2cde",
      "Version": "202107211419360059",
      "LastModifiedTime": "2021-07-08T14:19:36.0757847Z",
      "FileExtension": ".docx",
      "FileNameMaxLength": 0,
      "AllowAdditionalMicrosoftServices": true,
      "AllowExternalMarketplace": true,
      "DisablePrint": false,
      "DisableTranslation": false,
      "HostEditUrl": "https://someUrl",
      "ReadOnly": false,
      "RestrictedWebViewOnly": false,
      "SupportsCobalt": false,
      "SupportsFolders": false,
      "SupportsContainers": false,
      "SupportsLocks": true,
      "SupportsGetLock": true,
      "SupportsExtendedLockLength": true,
      "SupportsEcosystem": false,
      "SupportedShareUrlTypes": [],
      "SupportsUpdate": true,
      "SupportsRename": false,
      "SupportsDeleteFile": false,
      "SupportsUserInfo": false,
      "IsAnonymousUser": false,
      "IsEduUser": false,
      "LicenseCheckForEditIsEnabled": true,
      "UserCanAttend": false,
      "UserCanNotWriteRelative": true,
      "UserCanPresent": false,
      "UserCanWrite": true,
      "UserCanRename": false,
      "UserFriendlyName": "wopitest"
    }
```

My question: Why is the Add-Ins button not visible? How can I change this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To enable Add-Ins, log into your OOS and run the following command in PowerShell

`Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm -OfficeAddinEnabled:$true`

Then restart your WOPI server and clear the cache and refresh in the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, but I do not have an own OOS deployed. I rely on Microsoft Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

In mid-late 2021, MS started providing support for Add-Ins for WOPI. There is a new process in place to get Add-Ins enabled for your WOPI host. You need to raise a support ticket with MS to get this enabled.